# Text line manipulation with multiple matches in a line

Tags: regex, bash

I would like to do the following on a line in a bash script:

**Case 1**

```
"text1=text2 some text /orig/path/s/abc.la more text"
```

**required result:**

```
"text1=text2 some text /replacement/path/t/abc.la more text"
```

**Case 2**

```
"text1=text2 some text /orig/path/s1/abc.la more /orig/path/s1/xzy.la text"
```

**required result:**

```
"text1=text2 some text /replacement/path/abc.la more /replacement/path/xzy.la text"
```

so I want to replace the path of all instances of a filename in a line when it's matching with the given extension (in this case "*.la")

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: I'm totally unfamiliar in the regex world, I have problem with libtool while crosscompiling packages, unfortunately inserts wrong paths in the *.la file tehrefore prevents the the builds of another packages. An exact exaple of this is the following: orig line: dependency_libs=' -L/opt/mingw32/i686/lib -lws2_32 -lole32 -lwinmm -lshlwapi /lib/libintl.la lib/libiconv.la'  replacement line: dependency_libs=' -L/opt/mingw32/i686/lib -lws2_32 -lole32 -lwinmm -lshlwapi /opt/mingw32/i686/lib/libintl.la /opt/mingw32/i686/lib/libiconv.la'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is always the simplest pattern that works - since your required substitution appears to only need to "remember" the filename itself and isn't doing anything with the original path, you could use a non-greedily quantified wildcard `.*?` to eat up everything between the first and last `/` and make the pattern pretty simple:

pattern:  `/.*?/(\w+).la`

replace:  `/mypath/here/$1.la`

https://regex101.com/r/jTXm00/1/

Comment: This helped me, Thank you very much ! also the regex link helped me to solve my problem in different cases. The final sulution is here https://regex101.com/r/jTXm00/3, Only I added a space to the match pattern and add a space to the replace pattern.

Comment: SED do not accept "lazy" quantifier ("?"), so this regexp will not works well. instead use perl wich also supports in place editing, The final solution was the following to me:  perl -pi -e "s: \/.*?\/(\w+.la): \/newpatath\/\1:g" inputfile